# Reduce the height of empty lines in \lstinputlisting

Tags: listings, lstdefinestyle

I am using \lstinputlisting to present some of my code in a paper. As shown in this image: [image]

I intend to add empty lines between different parts of codes. However, I somehow want to reduce the height of these empty lines since they are occupying too much space.

Is there any way that I can control the height only for the empty lines by config the \lstset?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a hook that you can use:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
abc
abc

abc
\end{lstlisting}


\makeatletter
\lst@AddToHook{OnEmptyLine}{\vspace{-0.7\baselineskip}}
\makeatother
\begin{lstlisting}
abc
abc

abc
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly, very smart solution. Thanks

Comment: Can we apply this solution for all lines?