# How can I reduce the all lines height in \lstinputlisting

Tags: listings

I want to reduce all lines' height (empty space between each line) in `\lstinputlisting`, is it possible?

Original code is taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/660320/127048 , only `\usepackage[scale=0.9]{zi4}` is changed (smaller scale):

> ```tex
> \documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
> \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
> \usepackage{lipsum}
> \usepackage[nott]{newtxtext}
> \usepackage{newtxmath}
> \usepackage[scale=0.9]{zi4}
> \usepackage{listings}
> \usepackage{lstautogobble}
>
> \lstdefinestyle{mystyle}
> {
>     basicstyle=\ttfamily,
>     frame=single,
>     breaklines,
>     columns=fullflexible,
>     breakindent=1.2em,
>     breakatwhitespace,
>     escapeinside={(*}{*)},
> }
> \begin{document}
> abc\texttt{abc}
>
> \begin{lstlisting}[style=mystyle,autogobble,xleftmargin=1.1mm,xrightmargin=2.5pt]
>     function hello_world(*\,*)(uint a, uint b, uint c, uint d, uint e, uint f) public returns bool {
>         uint256 amount = 100
>         return true;
>     }
> \end{lstlisting}
> \lipsum*[2]
> \end{document}
> ```

[image]

Could be related to: [Reduce the height of empty lines in \lstinputlisting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/403976/127048)

Comment: is there really any space it is safe to remove? Your code is all lower case and has no descenders but add some gygyABC and the spacing is quite tight already?

Comment: Yes sir quite tight already, I just wanted to gain very little space like maybe `1mm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the baselineskip as part of the font size, so

[image]

```
    \documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage[nott]{newtxtext}
    \usepackage{newtxmath}
    \usepackage[scale=0.9]{zi4}
    \usepackage{listings}
    \usepackage{lstautogobble}

    \lstdefinestyle{mystyle}
    {
        basicstyle=\fontsize{10}{10.5}\ttfamily,
        frame=single,
        breaklines,
        columns=fullflexible,
        breakindent=1.2em,
        breakatwhitespace,
        escapeinside={(*}{*)},
    }
    \begin{document}
    abc\texttt{abc}


    \begin{lstlisting}[style=mystyle,autogobble,xleftmargin=1.1mm,xrightmargin=2.5pt]
        function hello_world(*\,*)(uint a, uint b, uint c, uint d, uint e, uint f) public returns bool {
            uint256 amount = 100
            return true;
        }
    \end{lstlisting}


    \lipsum*[2]
    \end{document}
```

Comment: For the `\footnotesize` , I should do `\fontsize{8}{8.5}\ttfamily` right?

Comment: @alper yes, or whatever looks right, but 8 is footnotesize in default classes